# Laravel validation of zip file content

Tags: php, laravel

I want to accept only file which has ".zip" extension. I added a rule mime-type `application/zip` to control this. But i dont know its content so i need to check zip file's content to avoid unknown files. How can I safely control the contents of a zip file?

I am using https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper to extract and
 laravel version is 5.5

```
public function store(Request $request, User $sharingUser) {
        $rules = [
            'patient_case_id'   => 'required|exists:patient_cases,id',
            'file'              => 'required|mimes:zip,rar',
        ];  
}
```

Uploaded zip file's content tree like this :

xxxx - MAIN FOLDER

|- aaaa.adf

|- bbbb.adf

|- cccc.adf

|- dddd.adf

|- aaaa.ocx

Folder can has only .adf and .ocx files... But i dont know how many files in folder.

**note: it is a RESTful API**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you use [PHP League's ZipArchive Adapter](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/zip-archive/) instead.

Create a new [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules). Set up the rule in the request and then define the logic.

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\ZipArchive\ZipArchiveAdapter;

$filesystem = new Filesystem(new ZipArchiveAdapter(getrealpath($value)));
```

In the `passes()` method, set the file-system up to read the file. I imagine you may need to figure out the path of the file in temporary storage `realpath($value)`.

Then flesh out the logic for the check. You could loop through the files within like so:

```
foreach ($filesystem->listContents() as $object) {
    if (!in_array($object['mimetype'], ['mimetype1', 'mimetype2'])) {
        return false;
    }

}
return true;
```

I can't remember if `listContents()` recursively lists all files, but there may be an option to make it do that, check their documentation. You don't have to use the mimetype comparison, just use whatever makes the most sense.

Comment: Neat approach! Few things: instead of `getrealpath()`, I needed to use `realpath()`. Also, `['mimetype']` was not an option so I used `['extension']`

Comment: There is no point of getting an extension and validate because any file can change it to another extension. eg) a png file can change it to jpg and this code will fail. We have to find out the mimetype of that file.

Comment: @AlbertRaj try `File::guessClientExtension()`

Comment: @Jonathan Not sure how can we use this File::guessClientExtension() in ZipArchiveAdapter.  Add the documentation or an example if possible

Comment: @AlbertRaj Look up the documentation for this method. Please up vote the answer if it helped you even slightly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to know the content of a zip folder without extracting it and then only accepting it right?

you can use this code to know the contents of a zip folder.

```
<?php
$za = new ZipArchive(); 

$za->open('theZip.zip'); 

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 
    print_r( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ); 
}
?>
```

and then you can check with your conditions.

you can find more about it in http://www.php.net/ziparchive

Comment: How do we know the mime type of each file in the zip ?